# How to convert an int to hex with leading zeros in Java?

Tags: java

I need to convert the numbers `1` to `255` (`address`) into hex values from `01` to `FE` (`hexAddress`).

There must be a leading 0 for values from `01` to `0F`, the letters must be uppercase, and there cannot be a `0x` prepended to the hex value.

Edit: This question is not a duplicate. The question that it is cited as a duplicate of has an accepted answer that does not work for this situation, nor does it fully explain how it works.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
String hexAddress = String.format("%1$02X",address);
```

`%1` means these flags are for the first argument. In this case, there is only one argument.

`$` separates the argument index from the flags

`0` is a flag that means pad the result with leading zeros up to the specified bit width.

`2` is the bit width

`X` means convert the number to hex, and use uppercase letters. `x` would convert to hex and use lowercase letters.

You can read more about the different possible arguments by examining the [Java Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) class.